Backup SQL Server databases in Parallel using Ola Hallengren script
We have an instance of over 200 large databases (between 100GB to 1.5TB) which take about 3 days to backup. We are in the middle of trying to improve this backup duration and want to consider the Ola Hallengren DatabasesInParallel option Ola Hallengren - SQL Server Backup
It says:

You can process databases in parallel by creating multiple jobs with the same parameters, and add the parameter @DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'.

I would appreciate some guidance on how to write the script to split up the databases into groups for each job to be run in parallel:
e.g.
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup, D:\Backup, E:\Backup, F:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Compress = 'Y',
@BufferCount = 50,
@MaxTransferSize = 4194304,
@NumberOfFiles = 4,
@CleanupTime = 24'
@DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'

Thank you

In this Github issue, Ola Hallengren explained that:

You need to create multiple jobs with the same parameters, and add @DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'. The jobs will then work together in processing the databases, using a queue - table.

To implement this, ensure that you:

Create multiple SQL Server Agent jobs that execute the dbo.DatabaseBackup stored procedure with the SAME set of parameters and set @DatabasesInParallel to 'Y'.

Your example code exec dbo.DatabaseBackup ... already qualifies that. You simply need to create n jobs and place the code inside each job. That means n backups will be processed in parallel. The value of n can be any number greater than 1, provided that sufficient resources (e.g., memory and CPU) are available. You can monitor resource usage during backups and adjust the number of jobs as needed.

Execute the scripts Queue.sql and QueueDatabase.sql to create queue tables in the same database where the dbo.DatabaseBackup is located. For example, this could be the master database. Different jobs use these tables to enqueue the next database to perform backup.


Thank you so much for this very helpful answer @TuyenNguyen. I will look  up the Github issue and carry out tests and feedback. I'm however not clear on how the job knows which database to backup?

When you set @Databases to USER_DATABASES, the jobs will back up only user databases, excluding system databases such as master, tempdb, msdb, and model. The QueueDatabase table likely serves as a queue, storing all user databases. Each job then dequeues one database at a time for processing until all databases have been backup.

I am sorry maybe you already have one job for SYSTEM_DATABASES, but so let you know, it is important to also backup system databases regularly as well, including master, msdb, and model databases: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-system-databases-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16. If so you can set EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = 'ALL_DATABASES'...

thanks again for above last two posts, very helpful. I will definitely feedback once I've had a chance to trial the solution. Yes, I have a separate job for SYSTEM_DATABASES. Much appreciated. Have a good Christmas break. I'll update in the new year.

What I have done in past for one of my customer is to create multiple jobs and  used the parameter @Databases like the one below to achieve something similar:
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = '%Prod%',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Compress = 'Y',
@BufferCount = 50,
@MaxTransferSize = 4194304,
@NumberOfFiles = 4,
@CleanupTime = 24'
@DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'
-- 2nd Job
What I have done in past for one of my customer is to create multiple jobs and  used the parameter @Databases like the one below:
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup

@Databases = '%Dev%',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Compress = 'Y',
@BufferCount = 50,
@MaxTransferSize = 4194304,
@NumberOfFiles = 4,
@CleanupTime = 24'
@DatabasesInParallel = 'Y'
